# Trigger function when user got registered in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

It's possible to add a function to get the username and user email when users register on Wordpress and then in that function call a Webservice to register the same user in another system? I know exists hooks and some others but I'm newbie with Wordpress and I don't know how to get this done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make WordPress do certain things through the functions.php file in the Theme or by creating a plugin for that purpose.

More about WordPress Functions - https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained

You can manipulate the user_register action hook to make it access another database and insert the details. http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register